# Wallet Connect is not working on mobile by using web3modal

Tags: wallet-connect, web3modal

gentlemen.
I am developing the web game on "Cronos" Chain and I have the issues in wallet connecting.
It is working on PC without no errors, but on mobile it is not working, also without presenting any errors.

Please let me what I made mistake on wallet connecting.
Here is my code

```
    const providerOptions = {
      injected: {
        display: {
          logo: "https://github.com/MetaMask/brand-resources/raw/master/SVG/metamask-fox.svg",
          name: "MetaMask",
          description: "Connect with MetaMask in your browser",
        },
        package: null,
      },
      walletconnect: {
        package: WalletConnectProvider, // required
        options: {
          chainId: config.configVars.mainnet.chainId,
          rpc: {
            [config.configVars.mainnet.chainId]: config.configVars.mainnet.rpcUrl,
          },
          network: "cronos",
          metadata: {
            icons: ["https://ebisusbay.com/vector%20-%20face.svg"],
          },
        }
      }
    };
   const web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
     cacheProvider: false,
     disableInjectedProvider: false,
     providerOptions, // required
   });
```